# Unique Stationary Distribution for Reducible Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Is it possible for a reducible markov chain to have a unique stationary distribution. Consider e.g. the markov chain with transition matrix below

$$A= 
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\\
  0.2 & 0.7 & 0.1 \\\
  0.3 & 0.3 & 0.4
\end{pmatrix}$$
I believe A is a reducible markov chain ({1} and {2,3} are two distinct classes of states). Once we visit state 1 we are stuck with state 1. However if we try to calculate its unique distribution it comes as pi_s = [1 0 0]. And if we start with any arbitrary probability distribution, after a while it seems we will converge to pi_s. I am not sure am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed this Markov chain is reducible, with two communicating classes, and the communicating class {1} is closed while the communicating class {2,3} is not. Every stationary distribution of a Markov chain is concentrated on the closed communicating classes, in the present case, only state 1 is in a closed communicating class. This proves without computation that the stationary distribution is unique and is the Dirac distribution on state 1.

Comment: @Did can you please recommend a source for concentration of stationary distributions on closed communicating classes? Thank you

Comment: @Sai Any textbook on finite Markov chains. Norris' *Markov chains* is available online.

Comment: @Did thank you very much. Could you please direct me more specifically? I couldn't find the statement.

Comment: @Sai One ends up leaving any non closed communicating class $C$ hence, for every initial measure $m$ and every state $i$ in $C$, $(mp^n)_i\to0$. If $m$ is stationary, $m=mp^n$ for every $n$ hence $m_i=0$. This proves that $m(C)=0$ for every non closed communicating class $C$ and every stationary distribution $m$.