# Markov Chain with two components

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am trying to understand a question with the following Markov Chain:

[image]

As can be seen, the chain consists of two components. If I start at state 1, I understand that the steady-state probability of being in state 3 for example is zero, because all states 1,2,3,4 are transient. But what I do not understand is that is it possible to consider the second component as a separate Markov chain? And would it be correct to say that the limiting probabilities of the second chain considered separately exist? For example, if I start at state 5, then can we say that the steady-state probabilities of any of the states in the right Markov chain exist and are positive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Actually this Markov chain is reducible, with two communicating classes (as you have correctly observed),

1. $C_1=\{1,2,3,4\}$, which is not closed and therefore any stationary distribution assigns zero probability to it and
2. $C_2=\{5,6,7\}$ which is closed.

As stated for example in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252084/unique-stationary-distribution-for-reducible-markov-chaine),

> Every stationary distribution of a Markov chain is concentrated on the closed communicating classes.

In general the [following holds](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~ejm/M3S4/NOTES3.pdf)

> **Theorem**: Every Markov Chain with a finite state space has a unique stationary
>   distribution unless the chain has *two or more* closed communicating classes.
>
> **Note**: If there are two or more communicating classes but *only one closed* then the stationary
>   distribution is unique and concentrated only on the closed class.

So, here you can treat the second class as a separate chain but you do not need to. No matter where you start you can calculate the steady-state probabilities and they will be concentrated on the class $C_2$.

Comment: Yeah, I see that little block in bottom-right corner of transition matrix :) $$\begin{pmatrix}
0 &\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{1}{2}& 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 &\frac{1}{2}& 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @Stef Thanks so much for the answer. One more thing that I am confused about. I read that a Markov Chain can only be considered to have a limiting distribution (and are ergodic) if "all" of its states are irreducible and non-transient, so when we obtain the steady-state probabilities by solving the simultaneous equations of the system as a whole, aren't they a limiting distribution? Or is there a difference between having a limiting distribution and being ergodic? Can we have a limiting distribution without the chain being ergodic?

Comment: When studying long-run behaviors we focus only on the recurrent classes. Limiting probabilities and stationary are different (but limiting are a subset of stationary). This is for the reason that for example the sequence $\{0,1,0,1,0,1,\ldots\}$ does not have a limit, but spends $1/2$ of time in state $0$ and $1/2$ of the time in $1$. So, to return to your question, the class $C_2$ is ergodic etc. but not the chain as a whole. Depending on the definition you can say that the limiting distribution is $0$ for states in $C_1$ but is better to say that you focus on $C_2$.