# Markov transition matrix: $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} P^n$ and $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n P^k$

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

Given the Markov transition matrix

$$P=\left( \begin{array}{ccccccc}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0 & 0.7\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0.4 & 0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0.4\\
0  & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0.3 \\
\end{array} \right)$$

write these two limits:

- $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}  P^n$
- $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}  \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n P^k$

Is there a systematic way to calculate these matrixes without computing every single entry?

---

I added a aswer, but it is incomplete.

Comment: for the first question see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1691605/how-many-stationary-distributions-does-a-time-homogeneous-markov-chain-have?rq=1. Your matrix is irreducible, so it will end up with stationary distribution in rows

Comment: Thanks, but this matrix is not irreducible: it contains two classes: states {0, 2} and states {1, 4} while state 3 is a transition state. So I can argue that rows 0 and 2 will be equale and the same the rows 1 ad 4. But rows 3? and How can I compute theme?

Comment: You are right. (misread the entries). Each recurrent class will have its own stationary distribution, with {0, 2} being also periodic

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea. By rearranging rows (and columns to have the same chain, just states relabeled), we are getting two block matrices for recurrent classes and one row for transient state
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0.4 & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & 0.4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0.3 & 0.7 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0.3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
Now, the third row of $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}P^n$ should be all zeros, because the state is transient, so the probability of finding chain in this state, given non-zero probability distribution of starting in this state is $0$. The Left-Upper block, due to periodicity, have no limit, it either \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\\\end{pmatrix} or \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}. Hence the $\lim$ itself doesn't exist. But, the second block matrix plays it good and have a $\lim$ \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}

Thus, the second question make sense, as LU block could be averaged
and the answer is
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{pmatrix}

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of the exercise, but I can't figure out how to computing the mean limit.

First, compute the stationary distribution:

- $\pi_0, \pi_2$ are undefined because states $0$ ad $2$ are periodic
- for $\pi_1, \pi_3, \pi_4$ we can use the definition of stationary distribution:
  $$\sum_i \pi_i=1$$
  $$\pi_j = \sum_{j \neq i} p_{i,j}\pi_i$$
  $$\pi_i \geq 0$$
  therefore:

  - $\begin{cases}
    \pi_1 + \pi_4 = 1\\
    \pi_1 = 0.3\pi_1 + 0.7\pi_4\end{cases} \implies \pi_1 = \pi_4=0.5$
  - $\pi_3 = p_{3,0} · \pi_0 + p_{3,1} · \pi_1 + p_{3,2} · \pi_2 + p_{3,4} · \pi_4$

.

## Solution to $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}  P^n$

.

Entries $ij$ of the matrix $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}  P^n$ will be $\pi_i u_{i, j}$, where $u_{i, j}$ is the probability to be absorbed in the class of state $j$, starting from $i$.

Using first step analysis we found:
$$
\begin{cases}
u_{0,0} = u_{0,2} = u_{2,0} = u_{2,2} = 0 \\
u_{1,1} = u_{1,4} = u_{4,1} = u_{4,4} = 0.5\\
u_{3,1} = u_{3,4} = \sum_i p_{3,i} u_{i,1} = 0.2 u_{3,1} + 0.4 u_{1, 1} \implies u_{3, 1} = 0.25 \\
\end{cases}
$$

All others absorbig probabilities are $0$.

Signing with a '-' the undefined probabilities:
$$
\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}  P^n =
\begin{pmatrix}
- & 0 & - & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 \\
- & 0 & - & 0 & 0 \\
- & 0.25 & - & 0 & 0.25 \\
0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

.

## Solution to $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}  \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n P^k$

.

It is the following but I can't figure out why:
$$
\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}  \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n P^k =
\begin{pmatrix}
0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0\\
- & - & - & - & - \\
0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 \\
0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0 & 0.25 \\
- & - & - & - & - \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Someone can complete this answer?